# Using GitHub markdown image tag but image is not displaying inline

Tags: github, markdown

I have a README.md in my GitHub repository and I have an image tag in it that looks like this:

```
![Wireframe001](wireframes/wireframe001.png?raw=true "Wireframe001")
```

and I can confirm that I have a wireframe relative to `README.md` at that path `wireframes/wireframe001.png`.

The image holder appears in the `README.md` and clicking on it takes me to the image but the image itself does not appear inline in `README.md`.

Comment: Does this problem still exist? I have a feeling that GitHub did not properly render images at that short period of time only.

Comment: I have attepted to recreate the issue here: https://github.com/PuZZleDucK/github-markdown-image-test and it seems to work as expected. Perhaps it is an issue with the image itself? or another part of the .md file? Can you share the link?